# How do I make grails choose the right JDK?

Tags: grails

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.5 with Oracle's Java 1.7 installed in addition to the mac's 1.6. 
I have my JAVA_HOME set and the JAVA_HOME/bin in the front of my path.
When I run a grails compile from the command line I can see it's choosing the Java 1.6 instead of 1.7.  How do I make the grails command-line choose the JDK I want?

```
➤ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
➤ echo $PATH
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin /usr/local/share/npm/bin /Users/kbrodhagen/bin /Users/kbrodhagen/.rvm/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/git/bin
➤ set -x JAVA_OPTS "-showversion"
➤ grails compile
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which shell are you using and exactly how did you set `JAVA_HOME`?  Grails should respect your `JAVA_HOME` setting as long as it is visible to the `grails` command, for example in bash you must `export` the variable rather than just setting it, in `tcsh` you would use `setenv` rather than `set`.

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can also remove `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` from your PATH as `/usr/bin/java` will automatically delegate to the appropriate `java` command for the current `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: The environment was it.  I'm using the fish shell and I wasn't setting the right flag on the command to export the variable.

For the record the right command is (use -x to export):
set -x JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to do it local to grails as opposed to the whole system...

Comment: @Spider I'd just create a shell script somewhere on your path (e.g. `~/bin/grails`) that sets JAVA_HOME and then delegates to the real grails script.  Or for a single project do `grails wrapper` and edit the generated `grailsw`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to localise the Java version only to Grails the best way is to edit below file,

```
.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh
```

You can set the JAVA_HOME in this file as below,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have Java 8 in my machine and here I am setting java 1.7 for grails *ONLY*.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me, even on Ubuntu, where I'd defined Java 8 as the default java using `alternatives`. My profile thinks I'm running Java 8 `javac -version` returns `javac 1.8.0_45`, but grails ignores /usr/bin/javac and instead searches under JAVA_HOME/bin for it.

Answer (score 1):

For the new SDKman method you can export `JAVA_HOME` in `[YOUR HOME]/.sdkman/candidates/grails/[concrete version or current]/bin/grails`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to be able to switch between a Java 7/Grails 2.4.4 project and a Java 8/Spring 4 project in Ubuntu 12.04 and certain things made this difficult:

- I'd [set Java 8 as the default version](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) after installing it using `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`, but that apparently creates `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh` containing `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME` and other env vars that prevented me from swapping the JDK.
- [This](https://gist.github.com/timyates/6461688) kinda worked, but the above env vars clouded things too much.

In the end, I removed both of the above items from my environment and the files in `/etc/profile.d` and I now:

- Change the JDK by running `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle` (or `java-7-oracle`) as mentioned in the webupd8 article;
- Run `gvm` to set the current or default grails and other tools as required

Seems messier than it should be, but I think it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/) to install Grails (which is the [currently recommended method](https://grails.org/download.html)), you can add any versions of Java you have installed to SDKMAN and it will manage them for you as well. For example:

```
sdk install java openjdk-8 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
sdk use java openjdk-8
```

Note that this will set `JAVA_HOME` for your user, so if you don't want that you may want to consider one of the other options.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

For more information: [SDKMAN local versions](http://sdkman.io/usage.html#localversion)